# Why the Android Custom Font changing for Menu items code is not working?

Tags: android, fonts, menuitem, typeface

I am trying to change the font style of my Android Menu bar and it's all items but my following code not showing any change to the application.

**JAVA Code-:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) 
{



    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);

    setMenuBackground(); 

    return true;

}


protected void setMenuBackground()
{


    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() 
    {

        public View onCreateView(String name, final Context context,
                AttributeSet attrs) 
        {

            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) 
            {

                try 
                {

                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                    final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {

                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);

                            ((TextView) view).setTextSize(20); 

                            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Arial.ttf");     

                            ((TextView) view).setTypeface(face);

                            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);


                        }

                    });


                    return view;

                }
                catch (InflateException e) 
                {



                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
                {



                }

            }


            return null;

        }}); 

}
```

**XML Code-:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Abc"/>


 <item
    android:id="@+id/xyz"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="XYZ"/>


  <item
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Andi"/>
```

This is the above code and i want to change all the font styles for all the Menu items but i am quite unable to do that.

Please help me out !!! Suggest me some good solution.